# nopCommerce inserting entity fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, nopcommerce

I'm creating import from XML function for categories.
First of all, using XDocument, I create list of categories to be added. I turned off isIdentity option for ID in Categories table, because I'm planning to use ID from XML.

XML example:

```
<cat>
<id>17</id>
<name>Category name</name>
<parent_id>0</parent_id>
</cat>
```

Then, I wrote method, which tries to get category by ID and update, or insert new:

```
var category = _categoryService.GetCategoryById(Id);
        if (category != null)
        {
            category.Name = model.Name;
            category.ParentCategoryId = model.ParentCategoryId;
            category.UpdatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            category.Published = true;
            category.Deleted = false;

            _categoryService.UpdateCategory(category);
        }
        else
        {
            category = new Core.Domain.Catalog.Category();

            category.Id = model.Id;
            category.ParentCategoryId = model.ParentCategoryId;
            category.Name = model.Name;
            category.UpdatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            category.CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            category.Published = true;
            category.Deleted = false;

            _categoryService.InsertCategory(category);
        }
```

And then comes the most weird - application throws exception: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'nopCommerce.dbo.Category'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
BUT even in debugger, category ID is not null.. Asking for help!
Thanks in advance!

Update: InsertCategory is a standard nopCommerce method:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Inserts category
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="category">Category</param>
    public virtual void InsertCategory(Category category)
    {
        if (category == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("category");

        _categoryRepository.Insert(category);

        //cache
        _cacheManager.RemoveByPattern(CATEGORIES_PATTERN_KEY);
        _cacheManager.RemoveByPattern(PRODUCTCATEGORIES_PATTERN_KEY);

        //event notification
        _eventPublisher.EntityInserted(category);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out, that I need to change mapping class as well as database, removing autonumber option from ID. That was another pain, but solution is:

instead of `this.HasKey(c=>c.Id)` use:

```
this.Property(c=>c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine presented here seems OK. I'd say you have a problem on your InsertCategory method which is most likely not making use of the id. This is just a guess... If this is not the answer, perhaps you can let us know what you have under it.

Comment: `public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

                this.Entities.Add(entity);

                this._context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                throw dbex;
            }
        }`
is a standard nopCommerce method. When I debug this, entity is not null and has the ID, that's the weirdest thing...

Comment: Man, I feel your pain. Hope you find the solution and post it as an answer so that others don't go through the same problem for so long.. Maybe submitting a bug to nopcommerce? Cheers